# Error trying to change SQL Server CE transaction isolation level

Tags: transactions, sql-server-ce, isolation-level

I want to change the transaction isolation level of a connection to SQL Server CE (3.5) according to the documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171885(v=SQL.105).aspx

So I send the following statement:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

And I get this error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 5,Token in error = TRANSACTION ]

What is wrong with my statement ?

Comment: The documentation link you posted is for SQL Server 2008 R2, not SQL Server CE. That could be part of the issue you're having.

Comment: No it's about compact edition. First words : "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5"

Comment: My mistake - I was looking at the version indicated in bold at the top of the page.

Comment: That's a quirk of SQL CE documentation :( it's mixed with other editions of SQL Server.